# r forestplot with 4 groups

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am interested in reproducing this example, below with 4 treatment groups , side by side, 4 columns instead of 2 as shown in this example. I cannot figure out how to, and I need some help.

`install.packages("forestploter")`

Example :

```
dt <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "example_data.csv", package = "forestploter"))
# indent the subgroup if there is a number in the placebo column
dt$Subgroup <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), 
                      dt$Subgroup,
                      paste0("   ", dt$Subgroup))

# NA to blank or NA will be transformed to carachter.
dt$`n` <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Treatment), "", dt$Treatment)
dt$`n ` <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), "", dt$Placebo)

# Add two blank column for CI
dt$`CVD outcome` <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
dt$`COPD outcome` <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")

# Set-up theme
tm <- forest_theme(base_size = 10,
                   refline_lty = "solid",
                   ci_pch = c(15, 18),
                   ci_col = c("#377eb8", "#4daf4a"),
                   footnote_col = "blue",
                   legend_name = "Group",
                   legend_value = c("Trt 1", "Trt 2"),
                   vertline_lty = c("dashed", "dotted"),
                   vertline_col = c("#d6604d", "#bababa"))

p <- forest(dt[,c(1, 19, 21, 20, 22)],
            est = list(dt$est_gp1,
                       dt$est_gp2,
                       dt$est_gp3,
                       dt$est_gp4),
            lower = list(dt$low_gp1,
                         dt$low_gp2,
                         dt$low_gp3,
                         dt$low_gp4), 
            upper = list(dt$hi_gp1,
                         dt$hi_gp2,
                         dt$hi_gp3,
                         dt$hi_gp4),
            ci_column = c(3, 5),
            ref_line = 1,
            vert_line = c(0.5, 2),
            nudge_y = 0.2,
            theme = tm)

plot(p)
```

**Expected Plot**
[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are the four groups?

Comment: @Quinten, the four groups are in the dataset `dt <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "example_data.csv", package = "forestploter"))` and they are passed into function `forest` as `dt$est_gp1,
                       dt$est_gp2,
                       dt$est_gp3,
                       dt$est_gp4` so on with their corresponding C.Is

Answer (score 0):

You can provide CI columns for each estimates. Below is a demo:

```r
dt <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "example_data.csv", package = "forestploter"))
# indent the subgroup if there is a number in the placebo column
dt$Subgroup <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), 
                      dt$Subgroup,
                      paste0("   ", dt$Subgroup))

# NA to blank or NA will be transformed to carachter.
dt$n1 <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Treatment), "", dt$Treatment)
dt$n2 <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), "", dt$Placebo)
dt$n3 <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), "", dt$Placebo)
dt$n4 <- ifelse(is.na(dt$Placebo), "", dt$Placebo)

# Add two blank column for CI
dt$Group1 <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
dt$Group2 <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
dt$Group3 <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
dt$Group4 <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")

p <- forest(dt[,c("Subgroup", as.vector(outer(c("n", "Group"), 1:4, paste0)))],
            est = list(dt$est_gp1,
                       dt$est_gp2,
                       dt$est_gp3,
                       dt$est_gp4),
            lower = list(dt$low_gp1,
                         dt$low_gp2,
                         dt$low_gp3,
                         dt$low_gp4), 
            upper = list(dt$hi_gp1,
                         dt$hi_gp2,
                         dt$hi_gp3,
                         dt$hi_gp4),
            ci_column = c(3, 5, 7, 9),
            ref_line = 1)

plot(p)
```